# Azure subscriptions returning 0 results

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to get all subscriptions for an user using Get-AzureSubscription cmdlet. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn790366.aspx

The result is empty. Although i am pretty sure i have a valid azure subscription and can see it through portal[image: see attached image]

Also is this the best way to get all subscriptions through REST
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790531.aspx

Comment: Did you use Add-AzureAccount to login? Or Add-AzureRmAccount/Login-AzureRmAccount?

Comment: I Used Login-AzureRmAccount . I have yellowed out the info in screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Login-AzureRmAccount, the command to list all subscriptions is Get-AzureRmSubscription.

This is because those are Resource Manager commands and you can't mix them with Service Management commands like Get-AzureSubscription.